# How do you set a applications default bucket name?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Google's documentation on [php file uploads](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/#createuploadurl_options) says the gs_bucket_name option is "The name of a Google Cloud Storage bucket that the blobs should be uploaded to. If you don't specify a value, the blob is uploaded to the application's default bucket." this defaults to "app_default_bucket". How is this default set?

Is this possible to change by a environmental setting in the app.yaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A default bucket is a new concept that is rolling out as part of replacing the old App Engine blobstore. When an app is created it will automatically be allocated an associated bucket in Google Cloud Storage - this will be known as the default bucket. The default bucket cannot be manually configured outside of this process.

At the moment this functionality is not available to existing apps, but they will ultimately have a default bucket created at some stage in the not too distant future that will become the default bucket.

However, for now, PHP apps will need to configure the bucket themselves as part of the options array that is passed to the `createUploadUrl` call.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I really like this idea. Is this going to still work for apps that don't have billing enabled?

Comment: Yes - it will detect bandwidth and storage costs from your apps quotas, so you will be able to consume the free quota for this bucket.